# $http not deserializing json properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am invoking a REST service that returns json using `angularjs $http` service in the following way:

```
$http.get(myUrl).success(function(data){
    var foo = data['foo'];
}).error(...);
```

The success handler is invoked, but `data` is not a json object, but a string which looks like escaped json, i.e.:

```
"{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

(with the quoutation marks and slashes). This is what I get in firebug (in the network tab).
When I issue the same request from the browser (Firefox), I get a correct json (both correctly displayed in the browser as well as on the network tab in firebug).

Also, when I use jquery `$.ajax` with `$.parseJSON` instead of `$http` it loads the object correctly.

Am I missing some configuration of the `$http` service?

Comment: Where are you getting the JSON from - Fiddler, network tab or somewhere else? Also, could you post the full JSON file? These might help in debugging what is going on!

Comment: What is the Content-Type on the response?

Comment: In the case when the request is issued from $http it is application/json;charset=UTF-8. When I issue the request from the browser window, it is text/html

Comment: I think your REST service is returning an escaped string (ie. the problem is with that rest service). Take a look at [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eHKdFBeXRyMmno0JCexd?p=preview). Yes, `$.ajax` works in a way, but you shouldn't have to use `$.parseJSON` there either. Do you have any control over that service?

Comment: Yes, I can change the service. But this is a very simple service in scala that uses spring @RestController returning a string that is created using jackson serialization

Comment: What does your service look like? It seems very likely it's getting serialized twice on the server.

Comment: It was a double-serialization issue indeed, thanks!